# How to copy directory from one Linux server to another with a minimum in-between period?

Tags: linux, rsync, scp

I have a rather big directory on one server (over 4000 files), which I'd like to copy to another server (which contains a previous version of this directory). `rsync` is the first option, but it will put the destination folder into waiting status for a rather long period of time (more than a minute).

I'd like to do it a bit differently:

1. `gzip` the source folder
2. `scp` the archive to the destination server
3. `gunzip` the file there
4. delete the archive at the source and the destination

What is the best way to accomplish all this?

Comment: What does "put the destination folder into waiting status" mean?

Comment: It means that some files are in new version already, while others are still in the previous one

Comment: What are the requirements you're not telling us about?  What's using the directory, how long can you live with them being different, what is it about rsync that your setup can't cope with, etc?

Comment: It's a production system, with thousands of PHP files. Every second it receives a number of HTTP hits. I can't afford to keep this directory in mixed versions for a minute. I can afford a few seconds though..

Comment: can you paste more informations about directory size and number of files ?

Comment: 4000 files, about 10Mb in size

Comment: So to be clear you are looking for [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) at the filesystem level.

Comment: Zoredache exactly, I'm looking for ACID at the FS level

Comment: You could probably do something with LVM, that would be completely atomic, though it might not be worth the LVM and administrative overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rsync` has `--delay-updates` which seems to be what you need:

«…

> This option puts the temporary file from each updated file into a holding directory until the end of the transfer, at which time all the files are renamed into place in rapid succession. This attempts to make the updating of the files a little more atomic. By default the files are placed into a directory named ".~tmp~" in each

…»

Comment: As an addition to poige's answer, I'll recommend the OP using the `lockfile` command that is part of the `procmail` set of tools to lock access to the directory from readers. `lockfile` or a similar tool will need to be used by the writer and the reader. That way the data presented to the reader is consistent and not in the middle of an update.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way, if you have the space, is to `rsync` twice. Keep two copies of the files on the destination machine. First do a remote `rsync` to update the inactive copy. Then do a local `rsync` to update the active copy from the inactive copy.

Answer (score 2):

rsync to a cold copy, then just change a *symlink* and delete the former active copy

Answer (score 0):

Stop the web service on the target server for 10 minutes, do the update in any way you feel is sensible (rsync is fine), then start the web service again.

Comment: Right, and I am guessing, that if you where in an operating room doing an organ transplant, you would suggest killing the patient, while you do the transplant and then shocking him back after the operation is complete?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise the web site was a life or death service.  If you can't tolerate 10 minutes of downtime on the website, then you needed to have a better plan in the first place.

Comment: This could also be a regular deployment scenario. And if you have a website that actually makes MONEY or where operation has been sold to a third party under SLA 10 minutes downtime per deployment can be dire.

Comment: Indeed, none of which is mentioned in the original question, which is why I specifically asked for what we weren't being told.  As you can see, the OP finally gave the actual requirement under prompting, after I'd written this answer.  This answer is valid for plenty of websites, and not valid for others, but since the question didn't stipulate any significant downtime limitations, I felt it was reasonable.  Jumping on it because you feel it doesn't work in business critical or life threatening situations is fine, but the OP didn't state that as a requirement.

Answer (score -2):

1-2-3: `tar -c -O <source folder> | gzip -c | ssh <destination server> "gzip -d | tar -x "`

4: `rm <source folder>`